# How to modify \AtBeginLecture?

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer to pepare my lectures.

I am using command `\AtBeginLecture{\frame{some text... \insertlecture}}` to insert a tile at the beginning of the lectures.

This put the desidered text at the beginning of *every* lecture. I woulkd like to start the text only from the second lecture onwards, not the first. How can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new counter and check if it is `1`. A nice side effect of this method is, that you can now access the number of your lecture via `\the\lecturecount`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcount\lecturecount
\lecturecount=0
\AtBeginLecture{%
    \advance\lecturecount by 1
    \ifnum\lecturecount=1
        % nothing to do here
    \else
        \frame{Lecture No.\ \the\lecturecount: \insertlecture}
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\lecture{Vector Spaces}{week 1}
\frame{First frame}
\lecture{Scalar Products}{week 2}
\frame{Second frame}
\lecture{Outer Products}{week 3}
\frame{Third frame}
\end{document}
```